# Find the average of sums for a tuple of objects in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
id, name, num_inputs, value
1, name1, 10, 5
1, name1, 10, 6
1, name1, 10, 16

2, name1, 10, 51
2, name1, 10, 45

3, name1, 20, 2
3, name1, 20, 7
3, name1, 20, 10
3, name1, 20, 11

4, name1, 20, 11
4, name1, 20, 25
4, name1, 20, 55

5, name2, 10, 1
5, name2, 10, 76
5, name2, 10, 13

6, name2, 10, 11
6, name2, 10, 44

7, name2, 20, 3
7, name2, 20, 8
7, name2, 20, 134
7, name2, 20, 111

8, name2, 20, 121
8, name2, 20, 215
8, name2, 20, 515
```

I would like to group them first by the name-num_inputs tuple and then for each same ID to find the average of its sums. That is, each name-num_inputs will have a number of values with the same id, for those I would like to group them together, sum them up and find the average among those.

So the output should be something like this (ideally in a bar chart):

```
(name1, 10): 28.5     [(((5+6+16)/3) + ((51+45)/2)) / 2]
(name1, 20): 18.91    [(((2+7+10+11)/4) + ((11+25+55)/3)) / 2]
(name2, 10): 28.75    [(((1+76+13)/3) + ((11+44)/2)) / 2]
(name2, 20): 173.83   [(((3+8+134+111)/4) + ((121+215+515)/3)) / 2]
```

Plot as a bar chart. Ideally I would also like to find the 95% Confidence Interval

That's what I have done so far but is not working:

```
values = df.groupby(['name', 'num_inputs', 'id'])['value']
err = [[], []]
for name, group in value:
    data = group.tolist()
    lower, upper = my_functions.calculate_95_confidence_interval(data)
    up = upper - numpy.mean(data)
    down = numpy.mean(data) - lower
    err[0].append(down)
    err[1].append(up)

data = df.groupby(['name', 'num_inputs', 'id'])['value'].sum().mean()

data.plot.bar(rot=0, ax=ax, yerr=err, legend=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['id', 'name', 'num_inputs'], as_index=False)['value'].mean()
df1.groupby(['name', 'num_inputs'])['value'].mean().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
    name  num_inputs       value
0  name1          10   28.500000
1  name1          20   18.916667
2  name2          10   28.750000
3  name2          20  173.833333
```

Comment: Implicit key conversion will be deprecated use `df.groupby(['id', 'name'])[['num_inputs', 'value']].mean()` instead. (Nice solution +1 either way)

Comment: Thank you! Do I really need the reset_index? I would like to keep the labels so when plotting they appear with their label..

Comment: @John  Yes, you need to reset_index so that the `name` and `num_inputs` fields got go back to the data column.   Alternatively, can also use `as_index=False` in  `groupby()` without `reset_index()`

Comment: @HenryEcker  Thanks!  Fixed the warning message now.  Thanks for the friendly reminder  :-)

Comment: Your first aggregation shouldn't be sum instead of mean?

Comment: @John  Since you want to get (5+6+16)/3 for the first group of `ID` =1, it is a mean. Otherwise, will be just (5+6+16) if used sum

Comment: Yes my mistake, it should have been sum. No worries, no need to update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how the posted code doesn't work.

Also it's not really clear what you want to do for/with the 95th percentile, especially since you seem to be calling a function, `my_functions.calculate_95_confidence_interval`, to calculate it.

Any way, this code will calculate the averages and create a rudimentary bar chart.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df_avg = df.groupby(['id','name', 'num_inputs' ]).mean().groupby(['name', 'num_inputs']).mean()

print(df_avg)

df_avg.plot.bar()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Well, the CI is used as error in the chart.